# Vue 3 (Vite) change build index.html filename

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm creating a Vue 3 application that includes Vite's building process, and I'm looking to change the final built index.html filename to index.html.php. I can't find any reference in their documentation. Is it even possible?

Comment: I guess you can modify the index file inside your `vite.config.js` -> `build: { rollupOptions: { ...` but it's just a guess.

Comment: I looked through the rollupOptions documentation but I couldn't find an option to change the compiled filename.

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to [add a Vite plugin](https://vitejs.dev/guide/using-plugins.html#adding-a-plugin) that renames the `index.html` of the bundle. For example, this Vite plugin takes a string and assigns that to `index.html`'s final name:

```js
/**
 * @param newFilename {string}
 * @returns {import('vite').Plugin}
 */
const renameIndexPlugin = (newFilename) => {
  if (!newFilename) return

  return {
    name: 'renameIndex',
    enforce: 'post',
    generateBundle(options, bundle) {
      const indexHtml = bundle['index.html']
      indexHtml.fileName = newFilename
    },
  }
}
```

Then use it in your Vite config:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    renameIndexPlugin('index.html.php'),
  ],
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-rename-index-html?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: Nice! You saved my receding hairline 

Comment: When running `npm run build` and afterwards `npm run serve` (running the built application  in preview mode) that leads into a 404 resolve, since the preview mode can't resolve the `indx.html.php` file. To make it work in production, you need to also point to that `index.html.php` file. Have not tried it yet, but will post it here when I am done.

Comment: This is really cool, but it doesn't work with other plugins such as [CRXJS](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/). The file may have been renamed, but `manifest.json` still retains the old path. Anyone know how to resolve this?